# EclipseLink and GlassFish: Predeployment fails: NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, eclipselink

When I try to deploy my EJB-application to glassfish (3.1.2), I randomly get "Predeployment Errors". Some times it works, sometimes it doesn't, with a 50%-chance.

I searched the internet for this problem, but it seems that I am the only one with this problem. I am not able figure out what the problem is by analyzing the stack trace, either.

Does anybody have an idea what's the problem here? This is really killing me.

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while preparing the app
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.OneToOneAccessor.process(OneToOneAccessor.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processNonOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1436)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1707)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1337)
    ... 46 more

SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SeatingPlannerEJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.OneToOneAccessor.process(OneToOneAccessor.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processNonOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1436)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1707)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1337)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring in, OneToOneAccessor, so is related to one of your @OneToOne relationships.  My guess is that it is using a mappedBy but the target relationship name is not correct.

Try to determine the mapping causing the issue and include the code for it.

Also try the latest EclipseLink release, from the source code it seem like it will throw a proper exception at least in the case of a missing mappedBy.

Comment: You were right. There was an "illegal" OneToOne-Relationship between a Class and it's superclass. Once I removed it, everything worked fine.